# Eclipse DDMS not showing anything but adb, ddms are working!

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

The eclipse DDMS perspective is not detecting any attached devices or even the emulator. I have tried using adb and ddms from the command line and both are working! What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the Android SDK setting from the eclipse preferences was reset and hence Eclipse was not able to detect the path to DDMS. This can be easily rectified by setting the path to the Android SDK base folder by going to Window-> Preferences->Android->SDK Location.

Answer (score 3):

If your device is not set in the `Development` section to `Stay awake (checked)`, this might get to be a regular problem. 
You should disable and then enable again the debug mode on your device.

Answer (score 1):

In my case logging level was not set in DDMS settings

Preferences -> Android -> DDMS 
and then selecting Info level worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all above dont work go to ddms
right click
select reset

Comment: I updated Eclipse and ADT and then all my tabs/windows in DDMS went away. This restored the ddms to something usable.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue, DDMS was not launching. At last, in Android Studio -> Terminal, entered command DDMS and press Enter. Then DDMS started working.