# how to detect the emulator in eclipse for android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running an application in emulator. After running the application eclipse dose not show the emulator in devices. What missing in my eclipse please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to restart the `adb server`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469723/eclipse-adb-and-ddms-not-detecting-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: Goto AVD Manager and start anyone emulator first; then goto run configurations, goto target tab and say "Always prompt to pick device". Now run the application and see if it is asking for selecting the emulator or not.....

Comment: If the emulator keeps bugging after a lot of trials.. I make a new one !

Comment: I think you have to restart your adb.exe file...

Comment: you can restart or kill adb by using Command propmt..

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally had this problem. Sometimes you need to restart the adb. You can do that from the devices view menu and `Reset adb` as shon in below screen. If that doesn't work, you may need to restart Eclipse; sometimes the plugin gets hopelessly confused.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need restart `adb server` .1st of kill adb server and then restart it.

1. You can kill and restart using command promt to use `adb kill-server` and `adb devices` commands
2. you can kill adb server from `task manager->application` and `rmove adb`

Comment: I have used adb kill-server command. I got the response as adb is not a command.

Comment: please set Environment variable in mycomputer property..
please set your adb path :c:/android-sdk/ platform-tools/adb kill-server

Comment: i am using linux and i am in not in administrator in user

Answer (score 0):

I did this many times and work for me. First of all you reach at your Android-Sdk path from command prompt.

> like: C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\

now write this two command one by one in command prompt.

> C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\ **adb kill-server**
>   C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\ **adb start-server**
>   * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
>   * daemon started successfully *

When you type start-server it will show above message. It means now you can see your emulator on Devices View.
I hope this will help you to show android Emulator again in Devices View.