# can't start android virtual devices after eclipse pachages update

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, updates, android-sdk-tools

I don't have experience with Eclipse, but some time ago, I've followed some tutorials and I have successfully build 2 android applications. After 6 months of not using Eclipse, when I opened I had to make  some updates, but my virtual devices doesn't start. I get the following message error:

> Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Connection attempts: 1

I've tried the following, but the end results are the same:
- deleted and made new virtual device
- reset adb from DDMS
- adb kill-server from cmd

I assume that I didn't install the right packages in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: did you install the system image ?

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse or restart your PC itself, it will release any hold resources for emulator services..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what's causing you the problem but have you tried downloading the Android SDK from this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) ? It includes Eclipse and the Android SDK you need to develop applications.
It is possible to make it work by getting first eclipse and after that install Android SDK aswell.

About your error I assume is a problem in system services as when you want to start an emulator it must start aswell a system process ... maybe that's not starting and in this case can be a problem with your Android SDK or it gets blocked in the background by your operating system (I'm not sure what's really happing though, this is a guess).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this way. Sometimes adb is not working even emulator is started.
Please follow the below link.

[how to detect the emulator in eclipse for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349411/how-to-detect-the-emulator-in-eclipse-for-android/18349737#18349737)