# Eclipse IDE cannot connect to Mobile Device

Tags: android, eclipse

I known there is lots of answers about this question, but still my mobile device not connected to eclipse IDE.

The following is what I already did:
1. restart adb or type command in cmd "adb kill-server/adb restart-server", eclipse find nothing in the devices.
2. execute netstat -aon|findstr "5037", finding there is only one process "adb" occupy the port
3. check the phone driver in device management, finding the phone is install correctly.
4. execute "adb devices":

```
List of devices attach    
1f06cbba        device
```

I thought may it's my phone's problem, so i remove it, and create a virtual device avd, the eclipse still don't work.

My Operating System is Windows 7 and Eclipse IDE Kepler.

can any body help me to successful run my first android helloworld?

Thanks a lot!!

additional explanation

1. debug mode is in phone is ON
2. adb is in the variable %path%(maybe some should answered)
3. try the latest adt-bunble in adroid website, it still don't work.

Comment: connect your android device as media device and then again give it a try.

Comment: Have you installed drivers?

Comment: @AtifFarrukh download the driver from the phone official site, follow the official instruction to install the driver.

Comment: @wqrahd try, but failed a gain.

Comment: @buf1024 go to Device manager -> you phone -> properties -> update driver -> Browse my computer -> select location `<sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\` and install then try.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh I download adt-bundle from android developer site, there is no such directory?

Comment: @buf1024 it must be where you extracted like eg D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

Comment: @AtifFarrukh there is only one directory in the sdk\extras dirctory "android", I download the google usb driver from adroid website, and try to install in, but promtes: not suitable driver.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android usage, belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: check your android manifest sdkversions and check that your device falls in the range of those.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning "developer options" on in your device. (Option you haven't tried).

To access these settings, open the Developer options in the system Settings. On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Comment: i download the latest adt-bundle from android website.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added adb in your class path variables? If not , you should append the class path with following paths :

```
 path-to-sdk/android-sdk/platform-tools
 path-to-sdk/android-sdk/tools
```

Comment: @buf1024 could you post a screenshot or your error log of what exactly haapens when to try to run the program?

Comment: [2014-02-11 13:32:55 - DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!    
[2014-02-11 13:32:55 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。    
[2014-02-11 13:32:56 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing `ADT Plugin`. Worked for me last time.

Answer (score 0):

Install your current mobile Adb USB driver and update Google USB driver

Answer (score 0):

Check the MTP/PTP mode for your device:
http://lh3.ggpht.com/-8UMNs7Vg_dY/UVC6_6PnbDI/AAAAAAAAAIg/NjKOvAp9cDs/02-select-camera-ptp-mode_thumb%25255B1%25255D.png%3Fimgmax%3D800

In some devices you can find this under Settings->Storage->Menu Options(three vertical bullet squares).

When you say->the phone debug mode is open, i assume your developer options usb debugging is already enabled

Comment: did you check it with a different data cable

Comment: i switch to another data cable, failed, 2.

Comment: Are you sure that PTP mode failed? which device are you using, restart eclipse, adb

Comment: the same happens if i use android virtual devices.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469723/eclipse-adb-and-ddms-not-detecting-android-emulator